# Update Not Null Column with Default Value Fails

Tags: oracle, null, default-value

Please forgive me if this is a basic question.  I'm not much of an Oracle developer and Google has failed me so I turn to you.

I have two schema's in the same database.  They both have the same structure.  I have a table with a column defined as...

longitude_coordinate   NUMBER(16,8) default 0 not null,

...if I run the query...

```
UPDATE table SET longitude_coordinate = null WHERE id = xxxxxxxx
```

...on one schema it succeeds on the other it fails with the error....

**ORA-01407**:

> cannot update ("SCHEMA"."TABLE"."LONGITUDE_COORDINATE") to NULL.

I'm assuming there must be some global option but I can't locate it for the life of me.

Comment: Does the value of `id` exist in both schemas?  If the `update` can't find any rows to change, the null constraint is never violated.

Comment: Either the two objects do not actually have the same definition and the "other schema's" table allows `NULL` values or the `UPDATE` statement in the "other schema" doesn't actually update any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to update not null column with null values and it will throw error for obvious reasons.
Can you check whether that not null constraint was disabled in the schema where the query was executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to set null values to a column that does not support nulls values, 
This should work:

```
UPDATE table SET longitude_coordinate = 0 WHERE id = xxxxxxxx
```

hope this helps !